# FBSDKShareDialog cancels when it should post

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I create a FBSDKShareDialog in code

```
- (void)shareWithFacebookDialog;
{  
  FBSDKShareLinkContent* content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
  content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Path Redacted"];
  content.contentTitle = @"Title Redacted";
  content.contentDescription = @"Description Redacted";

  FBSDKShareDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
  [dialog setMode:FBSDKShareDialogModeNative];
  [dialog setShareContent:content];
  [dialog setDelegate:self];
  [dialog setFromViewController:self];
  [dialog show];
}
```

The dialog launches and all the information is correct

[image]

But as soon as Post is tapped the dialog closes and the cancel delegate is called.

```
- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer;
```

Has anyone seen this? Found a way to overcome it?

Comment: Hmm, I don't get this at all. What version of the SDK are you using and what version of the FB app do you have? If you can consistently get a repro, I would suggest creating a sample app, and attaching it to a bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK share always returns sharerDidCancel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279243/facebook-sdk-share-always-returns-sharerdidcancel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replace your code with this

```
- (void)shareWithFacebookDialog;
{  
    FBSDKShareLinkContent content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
    content.contentTitle = @"ContentTitle";
    content.contentDescription = @"ContentDescription";
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
}
```

tell me if it works.

Comment: It works Mars. I think my code above with an instantiated FBSDKShareDialog was getting *killed* edit - you are in the lead for the 250 points!

Comment: I up-voted this answer because the code does work and answers the question on how to overcome it which is using FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet instead of FBSDKShareDialogModeNative.   But why the heck does using FBSDKShareDialogModeNative return to sharerDidCancel when you Post???  My content is exactly the same but it will not post using FBSDKShareDialogModeNative.

Comment: Note that `fromViewController` is mandatory for `FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet`!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to call the method right after login.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error || result.isCancelled) {

        } else {
            [self shareWithFacebookDialog];
        }
    }];
```

It works if I just call it without logging in (should already have valid token).

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [self shareWithFacebookDialog];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: [Facebook SDK share always returns sharerDidCancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279243/facebook-sdk-share-always-returns-sharerdidcancel/31297421#31297421)

My error was in the AppDelegate method:

here is a link with the solution http://jitu1990.blogspot.it/2015/05/share-with-facebook-from-ios-app.html

And here is the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL* )url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {   
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return [ [FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application :application
             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook SDK v4.5+, try this:

Objective-C

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com"];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

Swift

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = URL(string: "http://developers.facebook.com")
FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
```